# Updating form values on redux store on each change

Tags: forms, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

i'm currently trying to store some form input values on store each time they are changed. However on each new dispatch the string only takes into account the last-1 char.

Let's say i write Hello! on my input. In store it will save just Hello

This is most of my code in case you want to check it!

This is a custom hook to handle the input change:

```
import { useState } from "react";

export const useForm = (initialState = {}) => {
  const [values, setValues] = useState(initialState);

  const reset = () => {
    setValues(initialState);
  };

  const handleInputChange = ({ target }) => {
    setValues({
      ...values,
      [target.name]: target.value,
    });
  };

  return [values, handleInputChange, reset];
};
```

And this is my form component:

```
import React from "react";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { NFTFormUpdate } from "../../../actions/NFT";
import { useForm } from "../../../hooks/useForm";

export const NFTMintingForm = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const [
    { toAddress, name, landOwnerAlias, size, country, stateOrRegion, city },
    handleInputChange,
    reset,
  ] = useForm({
    toAddress: "",
    name: "",
    landOwnerAlias: "",
    size: 0,
    country: "",
    stateOrRegion: "",
    city: "",
  });

  const handleInputUpdate = (ref) => {
    handleInputChange(ref);

    dispatch(
      NFTFormUpdate({
        toAddress,
        name,
        landOwnerAlias,
        size,
        country,
        stateOrRegion,
        city,
      })
    );
    
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h2 className="text-center">Land NFT minting</h2>
      <form className="container">
        <div className="form-floating">
          <input
            id="toAddress"
            type="text"
            name="toAddress"
            className="form-control"
            placeholder="0x1234..."
            autoComplete="off"
            value={toAddress}
            onChange={handleInputUpdate}
          />
          <label htmlFor="toAddress">Land Owner Address</label>
        </div>
        <br />
        <div className="form-floating">
          <input
            id="name"
            type="text"
            name="name"
            className="form-control"
            placeholder="0x1234..."
            autoComplete="off"
            value={name}
            onChange={handleInputUpdate}
          />
          <label htmlFor="name">Land Name</label>
        </div>
        <br />
        <div className="form-floating">
          <input
            id="landOwnerAlias"
            type="text"
            name="landOwnerAlias"
            className="form-control"
            placeholder="Netflix"
            autoComplete="off"
            value={landOwnerAlias}
            onChange={handleInputUpdate}
          />
          <label htmlFor="landOwnerAlias">Land Owner Alias</label>
        </div>
        <br />
        <div className="form-floating">
          <input
            id="size"
            type="number"
            name="size"
            className="form-control"
            placeholder="0x1234..."
            autoComplete="off"
            value={size}
            onChange={handleInputUpdate}
            min={0}
            step={0.0001}
          />
          <label htmlFor="size">Land Size (m2)</label>
        </div>
        <br />
        <div className="form-floating">
          <input
            id="country"
            type="text"
            name="country"
            className="form-control"
            placeholder="0x1234..."
            autoComplete="off"
            value={country}
            onChange={handleInputUpdate}
          />
          <label htmlFor="country">Country</label>
        </div>
        <br />
        <div className="form-floating">
          <input
            id="stateOrRegion"
            type="text"
            name="stateOrRegion"
            className="form-control"
            placeholder="0x1234..."
            autoComplete="off"
            value={stateOrRegion}
            onChange={handleInputUpdate}
          />
          <label htmlFor="stateOrRegion">State or Region</label>
        </div>
        <br />
        <div className="form-floating">
          <input
            id="city"
            type="text"
            name="city"
            className="form-control"
            placeholder="0x1234..."
            autoComplete="off"
            value={city}
            onChange={handleInputUpdate}
          />
          <label htmlFor="city">City</label>
        </div>
        <br />
      </form>
      <br />
    </div>
  );
};
```

This is a demonstration of its current behaviour:
[image]

As you may see, the action gets triggered correctly 6 times, but it only saves data on store just until Hello

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Independently of the question, you are aware that you should [Avoid Putting live form state into Redux](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide/#avoid-putting-form-state-in-redux)?

Comment: Didn't have a clue about it, still before managing form state this way I was thinking it was a bad idea. Currently i just left all form state within a useState hook and works just fine :D

I appreciate this knowledge that you've shared with me <3